# Julia: question on comprehension of ODE solver interface

Tags: julia, differential-equations

In the solution handling section in the documentation of the package [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/basics/solution/) I found a comprehension over the solution example

```
[t + 2u for (u, t) in tuples(sol)]
```

The comprehension is clear but what is the meaning of `t + 2u` in this example? Just an arbitrary combination/function or is there a deeper reason behind? I do not see any practical benefits for this choice/combination.
Similarly,

```
[t + 3u - du for (t, u, du) in zip(sol.t, sol.u, sol.du)]
```

Same question here: What is the meaning of `t + 3u - du`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The comprehension is clear but what is the meaning of t + 2u in this example? Just an arbitrary combination/function or is there a deeper reason behind?

> Same question here: What is the meaning of t + 3u - du?

It's just some expression to show the feature.